# Asking out young person to coffee

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, usage

What would be a good way to ask a young woman to coffee?

Would “*Veux-tu du café?*” be correct?

I would like for it to sound casual. She's 20-something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ask someone to go have coffee with you, the simplest way is probably to ask:

> Veux-tu aller prendre un café?
>   Voudrais-tu aller prendre un café? *(seems a little more hesistant)*

You're asking if they want to grab a coffee. The part about sitting down in a coffee shop and talking is implied.

If you want to ask someone if they want a cup of coffee, like offering to get one or even pay for one, you can say:

> Veux-tu un café?

If you're at home and have the means to make and/or pour coffee, you can ask if they want some coffee:

> Veux-tu du café?

Comment: Thanks! Would it be unusual to just ask "café?" and signal at a coffee place? Or would it sound rude?

Comment: @user6051 If you're walking in front of a coffee place, or at least can see a coffee shop, that would be just fine.

Comment: @user6051, if you found the answer useful you should consider [accepting](http://french.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it and also up-voting.

Comment: @Marc Ok, did it. New to stack exchange. Thanks

Comment: @Kareen Btw, I see you're from Quebec and reside in California. I'm in California too and hope to visit Montreal soon.

Comment: @user6051 Cool! I hope you like it! Definitely a nice place, and you'll be able to practice your French if you want to (or not)!